# Server app. How to fix / re-enable broken VPN after update to Mojave?

Tags: vpn, server.app, mojave

After updating to Mojave, the "Server" app no longer included a GUI for VPN.

I found [others having the same problem](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/vpn-server-for-mojave.2142862/), and there is an [official PDF-file that goes through the migration progress](https://developer.apple.com/support/macos-server/macOS-Server-Service-Migration-Guide.pdf).

How ever, the instructions in the PDF included at least one incorrect command to run in the terminal, and the others where (due to line-breaks) not usable by just copy-paste.

I also had permission problems leading to not being able to edit/save a newly created file.

Answer (score 6):

These instructions are largely the same as the ones in the [official PDF-file that goes through the migration progress](https://developer.apple.com/support/macos-server/macOS-Server-Service-Migration-Guide.pdf), but with the (hopefully) helpful addition that the the incorrect command is corrected and the other commands are copy:able as-is.

1. Turn off the VPN service in the Server app. (If visible. For me it was not.)
2. Make sure you are in the `wheel` group. I followed [these steps (link )](https://superuser.com/a/192144/819129)
3. Open Terminal (where the rest of the instructions will be executed)  and go to the appropriate directory with:

   `cd /Library/LaunchDaemons`
4. Create an empty file called `vpn.ppp.l2tp.plist` in current directory with:

   `sudo touch vpn.ppp.l2tp.plist`
5. Set the right owner for the file with

   `sudo chown root:wheel ./vpn.ppp.l2tp.plist`
6. Open the file with `nano` (to avoid problems with saving that can occur if you use TextEdit or similar):

   `sudo nano vpn.ppp.l2tp.plist`
7. Copy paste the content below into `nano`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
   “http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
     <dict>
       <key>Disabled</key>
       <true/>
       <key>EnableTransactions</key>
       <true/>
       <key>Label</key>
       <string>vpn.ppp.l2tp</string>
       <key>KeepAlive</key>
       <true/>
       <key>Program</key>
       <string>/usr/sbin/vpnd</string>
       <key>ProgramArguments</key>
       <array>
         <string>vpnd</string>
         <string>-x</string>
         <string>-i</string>
         <string>com.apple.ppp.l2tp</string>
       </array>
       <key>EnableTransactions</key>
       <false/>
       <key>EnablePressuredExit</key>
       <false/>
     </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
8. Save with changes by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>, confirm file name with <kbd>Enter</kbd> and close nano with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>.
9. Load your new file by running:

   `sudo launchctl load -w ./vpn.ppp.l2tp.plist`
10. Verify with:

    `launchctl print system/vpn.ppp.l2tp`

These steps worked for me. Hopefully they can help for someone else that, like me, struggled to get the VPN feature up and running again after macOS Mojave update.

The [official PDF guide](https://developer.apple.com/support/macos-server/macOS-Server-Service-Migration-Guide.pdf) (mentioned above) has some additional information about "Ongoing management":

> Settings can be changed after vpnd is configured by editing the
>   `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/
>   com.apple.RemoteAccessServers.plist` file. Refer to the vpnd (5) man page for details on the configuration format. After changes are made, you can have the service reread the configuration file by executing the command
>   `sudo killall -HUP vpnd`.

Comment: If you are still running Server.app to create new users with recoverable passwords (needed for vpn) there may be a conflict with the launchd plist label. If vpnd keeps getting turned off after running Server.app, try changing the label in your /Library/LaunchDaemons/vpn.ppp.l2tp.plist to something other than "vpn.ppp.l2tp" and reloading the job.

Comment: Why does this launchd plist first enable and then disable "EnableTransactions" ? Also it disables "EnablePressuredExit" but isn't that the default anyway?